# how to create a menu in html dynamically

Tags: html, menu

**I'm not sure if I am using the proper term when I refer to "dynamically. ***

I want to have a simple, one level, menu displayed on all 80 pages of my site. The menu items will change periodically - new items added, some removed, etc... What is the best way to create this menu so I don't have to update all 80 pages? FYI: I'm not too knowledgeable in all the scripting languages. Thank you.**

Comment: HTML doesn't have any dynamic capabilities. So for dynamic updating/creation you're going to have to use either client-side (JavaScript, or its libraries) or server-side (ASP, .NET, PHP, Ruby, or possibly [server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)...) scripting. Are there any approaches in particular with which you'd be more comfortable?

Comment: Does your server support PHP or SSI directives?

Comment: @Halo, a typo. It was spelled correctly in the question itself.

Comment: sorry, just saw it :). BTW, if you use a <frame> tag, that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a master page if your working in any one of the "major" web frameworks. You put a lonely HTML tag up there so I'm not sure if this NEEDS to be purely HTML and nothing else.

Comment: but it dosint working with .html file visit :http://akashlive.com/1/menu1.html and view the source.. what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use PHP.

Name all your files so they end in php instead of html, and make a file called menu.php.

Copy your menu into menu.php, then no your other pages where you want the menu, type:

```
<? include("menu.php"); ?>
```

and the menu will appear like magic!

I would also suggest SSI, but they are often disabled on shared hosting in my experience.

Comment: Definitely the best way to go in regards to this question.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i found it anothersite.. and i tried it but iot dosint working in html page means .html file it only working in .php file.. but i want to make .html file.. is there any way to make it using css

Comment: I'd recommend continuing to read up on this sort of thing, your understanding of the difference between CSS, HTML and PHP seems quite mixed up.